# Vala syntax for delegates?

Tags: delegates, vala

first, some definitions from /usr/share/vala/vapi/libarchive.vapi

```
[CCode (cprefix="ARCHIVE_", lower_case_cprefix="archive_", cheader_filename = "archive.h")]
namespace Archive {...
[CCode (instance_pos = 1.9, cname="archive_open_callback")]
    public delegate int OpenCallback (Archive archive);
    ...
    [CCode (cname = "struct archive", free_function="archive_write_finish")]
    public class Write : Archive {...
            public Result open (
                    [CCode (delegate_target_pos = 0.9)] OpenCallback ocb,
                    [CCode (delegate_target_pos = 0.9)] WriteCallback rcb,
                    [CCode (delegate_target_pos = 0.9)] CloseCallback ccb
            );
    }
}
```

then my code

```
int mOpenCallback (Write archive)
{
    return Result.OK;
}

void foo(){...
Write archive = new Write();
archive.open(mOpenCallback,mWriteCallback,mCloseCallback);
...}
```

results : error: Assignment: Cannot convert from `mOpenCallback' to`Archive.OpenCallback'

what's wrong with it ?

then I tried this instead

```
namespace Archive {
int OpenCallback (Write archive)
{
    return Result.OK;
}
}

void foo(){...
Write archive = new Write();
archive.open(OpenCallback,mWriteCallback,mCloseCallback);
...}
```

but it outputs :  `Archive' already contains a definition for`OpenCallback'

```
void foo(){...
Write archive = new Write();
Archive.OpenCallback t = mOpenCallback;
archive.open(t,mWriteCallback,mCloseCallback);
...}
```

outputs  error: Assignment: Cannot convert from `foo.mOpenCallback' to`Archive.OpenCallback'

Answer (score 1):

`mOpenCallback` has takes an argument of type `Write`, not `Archive`, so it has a different type from the delegate `OpenCallback`. If you expect `Write`, you should perform the cast from `Archive` to write inside your call back.

Comment: My original code for callback was "public int mOpenCallback (Archive archive){...}" but this failed with error: `Archive' is not a type. So I thought Archive was virtual (there's no ctor for Archive in the .vapi) or something like that. In fact, it looks like I must prefix the classname (Archive) with the namespace (Archive too). Using mOpenCallback (Archive.Archive archive){...} it runs fine. So the problem was somewhat related to using a Write parameter instead of a Archive one.